# Coreplot CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic and repetitive labels

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic and it works great on labeling and ticks. The problem I have is when the user zooms-in too much until a point that the labels become the same. E.g. on Y axis I get 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,...

To fix this I looked into the the newRange.lengthDouble value of YAxis in

```
-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange*)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate;
```

and find-out manually that where exactly this starts to happen. and then used the value to limit the pinching by:

```
if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY) {

    //to avoid having e.g. 3,3,3... on all ticks on Y axis
    if (newRange.lengthDouble < 7){
        return [(CPTXYPlotSpace*)space yRange];
    }
}
```

This certain value seems to be dependent on the size of the chart container and the range of the numbers plotted. Do you see/have any corrolation between these so we can avoid the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a reasonable solution. Other alternatives include changing the label formatter to show digits after the decimal point or switch to the equal divisions labeling policy.

Comment: Tnx Eric but the approach I made doesn't work in all situations. I was not really familiar with terms location and length back then. I also didn't know that the duplicate values are indeed the values with more accuracy which were shown in a fixed accuracy level. E.g. 2.4, 2.4, 2.4 are indeed (2.41, 2.42, 2.43).

There must be a better solution to avoid duplicates with automatic policy. I'm desperately spending time on this. I don't want to use other polices as I have 10 charts with different data.

Comment: The labeling code doesn't know or care how the tick locations will be formatted. It just tries to find a set of evenly spaced locations that fall on "nice" values. Use the plot space delegate to adjust the label formatters as the length of the plot ranges change. With a small range, you'll need more decimal places to show the different location values. With a very large range, maybe switch to scientific notation or a suffix that indicate a multiple like M (1,000,000) or K (1,000).